# How to get raw XML code from XML::Twig element

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I'm a super-beginner with XML::Twig. I have an XML::Twig element with some HTML code in it.  I can do

```
$element->text
```

And get the text from it, but it strips out all the HTML tags, making them children.  Is there anyway to just get the full code from the element?  I'm even ok if it's encoded with html entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$elt->sprint` or `$elt->inner_xml` depending on whether you want the element start and end tags to be included (`sprint`) or not (`inner_xml`)

Comment: `inner_xml` excludes the element's own tags. The canonical way of doing this is with `toString`

Comment: I think I mentioned in the answer that `inner_xml` excluded the tags for the element. As for the canonical way... am I allowed to have some input here? ;--) (`sprint` existed way before `toString`, which AFAIR was added at the same time as full XPath support)

Comment: @mirod: Fair enough. All I meant is that the canonical way of stringifying *anything* is to use its `to_string` or `toString` method if it has one.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \$element;
```

or:

```
$element -> print();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is

```
print $element->toString;
```

Comment: You had me worried for a moment that I had done it and forgotten about it. Then I checked and got the usual `XML::Twig::Elt=HASH(0x999b8d8)`. I am still (somewhat) sane!